Why am I getting an error 500 for a validation (ConstraintViolationException) instead of a BAD_REQUEST 400
I've created a simple endpoint (quarkus-rest-jsonb: 3.10.2) to create a user. I'm calling the endpoint with an invalid email and expecting an validation error to return me a bad request 400 response. But I'm getting a 500 one.
Could someone tell me what am I missing ?
  @POST
  public Uni<RestResponse<UserDto>> create(@Valid UserNoIdDto userNoIdDto) {
    if (userNoIdDto == null) {
      throw new WebApplicationException(MSG_INVALID_PAYLOAD, 422);
    }
    return Panache.withTransaction(() -> userRepo.persist(mapper.toNoIdEntity(userNoIdDto)))
        .map(created -> RestResponse.status(Status.CREATED, mapper.toDto(created)));
  }


2024-06-01 08:43:30,546 ERROR [http-problem] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-3) status=500, title="Internal Server Error": org.hibernate.HibernateException: jakarta
.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [com.cvgaviao.api.app_mngt.entities.User] during persist time for groups [jaka
rta.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
        ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='must be a well-formed email address', propertyPath=email, rootBeanClass=class com.cvgaviao.api.ap
p_mngt.entities.User, messageTemplate='{jakarta.validation.constraints.Email.message}'}
]
        at org.hibernate.reactive.session.impl.ReactiveExceptionConverter.convert(ReactiveExceptionConverter.java:28)


Can you share a sample we can run to see where 500 is coming from?

Well, the error above is happening in my company's project that already contains models that can't be shared. I will prepare a simple one in the end of the day.

@geoand, I have created the sample here: https://github.com/cvgaviao/quarkus-issue

What kind of REST request would I need to make in order to surface the issue?

Just go to the swagger UI and try to create (post) a new item using the default sample that is suggested.

You don't have any Jakarta Validation annotation on UserNoIdDto, so what is happening is that Hibernate Reactive is trying to persist the entity and failing

Oh, sorry for the late answer, I was on vacation.
I just thought that just having the validation on the Entities would be enough. thanks for your time though.
